# How would you design an algorithm to solve this decision problem?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, decision-theory, rounding-error, decision-problems

Suppose I want to design an algorithm that, for an arbitrary polynomial $p$, returns YES iff there are two roots $z_1$ and $z_2$ of $p$ such that $\left|z_1 - z_2\right| = 1$.

How do I design such an algorithm, given that any computerized root-finding algorithm will only give the roots of arbitrary $p$ approximately?  It would seem that some error tolerance would be required -- say, returning YES iff $1 - \epsilon < |z_1 - z_2| < 1 + \epsilon$.  But even then, how to decide which $\epsilon$ is appropriate to avoid false positives?  Is there a way of bounding the probability of an incorrect decision given an error tolerance of $\epsilon$?  Etc.

Comment: Not sure there is a good algorithm for this... By good, I mean numerically stable and efficient.

Comment: In general, root-finding algorithms let you to find roots with any precision. Thus, you can set precision to $\epsilon/2$ to avoid false positives. You should decide what $\epsilon$ should be for your purposes.